# Need 3 separate outputs

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, do-loops

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){

    int row, 
        column = 0,
        colCount = 3,
        rowCount = 3;

    //for loop
    for (column; column < colCount; column++){

        for(row = 0; row <= (rowCount - 1); row++){

            cout << column << " " << row;

            if(row < (rowCount - 1)){
                cout << ", ";           
            }

        }

        cout << endl;

    }

    //while loop
    while(column < colCount){

        while(row < rowCount){

            cout << column << " "<< row;

            if(row < (rowCount - 1)){
                cout << ", ";           
            }

            row++;          

        }

        cout << endl;   
        column += 1;
        row = 0;
    }

    //do while loop
    do{
        do{
            cout << column << " "<< row;

            if(row < (rowCount - 1)){
                cout << ", ";           
            }

            row++;  
        }while(row < rowCount);

        cout << endl;
        column +=1;
        row = 0;
    }while(column < colCount);

}
```

When commenting out 2/3 loops, each one will produce the wanted output.
All together it seems to run on top of each other and adds extra output.

### Current output:

```
0 0, 0 1, 0 2
1 0, 1 1, 1 2
2 0, 2 1, 2 2
3 3
```

### Wanted output:

```
0 0, 0 1, 0 2
1 0, 1 1, 1 2
2 0, 2 1, 2 2

0 0, 0 1, 0 2
1 0, 1 1, 1 2
2 0, 2 1, 2 2

0 0, 0 1, 0 2
1 0, 1 1, 1 2
2 0, 2 1, 2 2
```

How do I get an output out of each loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the `for` loop as it is:

```
    for (; column < colCount; column++){
        for(row = 0; row <= (rowCount - 1); row++){
            std::cout << column << " " << row;
            if(row < (rowCount - 1))
                std::cout << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

Now `column` and `row` gets to 3 in the `for-loop` above, which makes it the `while loop` never going to be executed. So, you need to make both of them to `0`.

And, the third `do-while` loop always executes before any condition checks, thats why you get `3 3`

Anyways, here is a solution for your problem.

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    int row, column = 0, colCount = 3, rowCount = 3;

    //for loop
    for (column; column < colCount; column++){
        for(row = 0; row <= (rowCount - 1); row++){
            std::cout << column << " " << row;
            if(row < (rowCount - 1))
                std::cout << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    //while loop
    column = 0;
    row = 0;
    while(column < rowCount){
        while(row < rowCount){
            std::cout << column << " "<< row;
            if(row < (rowCount - 1))
                std::cout << ", ";
            row++;          
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;   
        column += 1;
        row = 0;
    }
    //do while loop
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    column = 0;
    row = 0;
    do{
        do{
            std::cout << column << " "<< row;
            if(row < (rowCount - 1))
                std::cout << ", ";
            row++;  
        }while(row < rowCount);
        std::cout << std::endl;
        column +=1;
        row = 0;
    }while(column < colCount);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You should initialize the `column` at the beginning of each loop to `0`.
2) Within the `while` and `do` loops, initialize the `row` to `0` before entering the inner-loop

The output `3 3` at the end is due to a single entrance in the `do-while` loop.